# How to create a checkbox for multiple choice on PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have an `input field` I changed it to a checkbox for `multiple choices`.
The worry here I can't add the `checkbox`, I mean that my user should click on `Ctrl` and select on the same time several choices. You can see it in this Image:

[image]

This following my code of the form:

```
$app->get('/Chart/{currency}/{year}/{zone}/{lru}....... , function(Request $request,...... $repsite, $lru, $contract, $forecast) use ($app) {
if ($app['security']->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    ///start form 
    $user = $app['security']->getToken()->getUser();        
    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')->setMethod('GET')
    .
    .
    .
    .
 ->add('lru', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(                 

                    '\'ATSU\'' => 'ATSU',
                    '\'APCC\'' => 'APCC',
                       .....
                     ),

                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'empty_value' => 'ALL',
                    'empty_data' => NULL,
                    'multiple' => TRUE                      
                    //'expanded' => TRUE
                ))
```

I want do a classic checkbox like this on the right:

[image]

I did a research on forums I found that I should use `multiple` and `expanded` and to set them to `TRUE`. When I add `expanded=TRUE` list became very "ugly", I give you a screensheet:

[image]

Can you please tell me how can I change my code to do a checkbox for `multiple choice`like in the picture above.
I hope that I find solution. Thank you.

Comment: All checkboxes to be multiple must have the same name following `[]` characters. Like this: `<input name="multi[]" value="1" /> <input name="multi[]" value="2" /> etc`

Comment: I did a table in my HTML, just I called all the function concerned to a choices type in my routes.php. Can you please suggest me some solution compatible to my code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can do this, this is implemented in this with code.
you will require jquery to do this.

change this code according to your use

https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri

```js
/*
 Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery - May 27, 2013
 (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
 license: https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
  } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida");
    $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 14px/100% "Andale Mono", AndaleMono, monospace;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #374954;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown dd,
.dropdown dt {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown ul {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}

.dropdown dd {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown a,
.dropdown a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown dt a {
  background-color: #4F6877;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
  min-height: 25px;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  width: 272px;
}

.dropdown dt a span,
.multiSel span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3px 2px 0;
}

.dropdown dd ul {
  background-color: #4F6877;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  width: 280px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown span.value {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown dd ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown dd ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  background-color: #6BBE92;
  width: 302px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dropdown"> 
  
    <dt>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="hida">Select</span>    
      <p class="multiSel"></p>  
    </a>
    </dt>
  
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
  <button>Filter</button>
</dl>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but I can't do this solution because I added all the choices in my routes,  and in html I just did a table that contains several columns, in each column I called the function concerned. Can I change my code here in my routes ?

Comment: can you please suggest me some solution compatible with my form on php, thank you.